# store diskspace value into variable

Tags: du

Using `du` command to get disk space, but only wanted the value, without the path. I am able to print using `awk`, but how to store only the value into variable?

```
du -sh $path | awk '{print $1}'
27G


du -sh $path
27G     $path
```

Comment: `var=$(du -sh "$path" | awk '{print $1}'); echo "$var"`

Comment: how about in perl?

Comment: Perl is overkill compared to awk for something so trivial but `... | perl -lane 'print $F[0]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variable to capture and store the output of `du` command:

```bash
disk_space=$(du -sh $path | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$disk_space"
```

Comment: For robustness, [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable), though, especially `"$path"`